# Python 2 import error: cannot import name unpack_labeled_data

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I m trying to import import numpy as np. This is my code

```
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

img = cv2.imread('messi5.jpg',0)
plt.imshow(img, cmap = 'gray', interpolation = 'bicubic')
plt.xticks([]), plt.yticks([])
plt.show()
```

But I get an error,

```
C:\Python27\pythonw.exe C:/Users/baqir/PycharmProjects/untitled/cdsk1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:/Users/baqir/PycharmProjects/untitled/cdsk1.py", line 2, in <module>
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 29, in       <module>
from matplotlib.figure import Figure, figaspect
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 36, in <module>
from matplotlib.axes import Axes, SubplotBase, subplot_class_factory
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
from ._subplots import *
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_subplots.py", line 10, in <module>
from matplotlib.axes._axes import Axes
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_axes.py", line 14, in <module>
from matplotlib import unpack_labeled_data

ImportError: cannot import name unpack_labeled_data `
```

I googled it but did not find any solution. Can anyone tell what here I m doing wrong?

Comment: Please add the full error traceback, not just the last line.

Comment: @cel added full traceback

Comment: `unpack_labelled_data` is a decorator function that should be defined in `C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py` ([see here](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/0a7a41d6db7a09ecb269634f6991c1e3171b6fa0/lib/matplotlib/__init__.py#L1594-L1856)). I'm guessing there must be something broken about your matplotlib installation. How did you install it?

Comment: I had the same error and could only fix it with a full system update (`sudo apt-get upgrade`) including many python packages which apparently fixed the broken matplotlib installation.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and fix it just now.My OS is Windows too, so you just need to upgrade your the version of [matplotlib](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/matplotlib/).I install matplotlib-1.3.1 result in import error and upgrade it to matplotlib-1.5.1 everything is OK.

Comment: I'm running onto this problem on linux with matplotlib 1.5.1

Answer (score 0):

I'm certain this is an installation issue after having installed an older version of matplotlib. Installing a new version of matplotlib on top of the old version did not fix this error for me however.

**Edit**: I fixed this by running uninstalling matplotlib twice. Matplotlib `1.5.1` was installed on my system, as well as a Matplotlib `1.2.0` egg.

```
pip uninstall matplotlib
pip uninstall matplotlib
pip install --upgrade matplotlib
```

---

## Linux

I ended up having to install everything in a `virtualenv` to get past the error(even though I had the latest version of matplotlib in my system).
You may need to install virtualenv via pip or your package manager.

```
virtualenv -p $(which python2) py2k
source py2k/bin/activate
pip install matplotlib numpy
```

---

## Windows

you can use `conda` from [`Miniconda`](http://conda.pydata.org/miniconda.html) to install pre-compiled python modules (if you and don't want to got through the hell of pip on Windows)

```
conda create --name py2k python=2
activate py2k
conda install matplotlib numpy
```

You can also just use [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads) which has `matplotlib` and `numpy` bundled in the Python 2 interpreter.