# Error while importing matplotlib.pyplot Python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a problem while importing matplotlib.pyplot , I have python2.7 windows 7 64bits

```
>>> import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#16>", line 1, in <module>
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\__init__.py", line 129, in <module>
    from matplotlib.cbook import is_string_like
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook.py", line 28, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 180, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from type_check import *
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 8, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
    import function_base
  File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\function_base.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .numeric import result_type, NaN, shares_memory, MAY_SHARE_BOUNDS, TooHardError
ImportError: cannot import name shares_memory
```

Please help

Comment: matplotlib is difficult to install, with all its dependencies, [in Windows](http://matplotlib.org/users/installing.html). How did you install it?

Comment: Check this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34950238/5510499

Comment: looks like your numpy installation is broken, try reinstalling.

Comment: I follow same procedure for both pkg , I download extension packages and install it with pip install

Comment: pip install "matplotlib-1.5.1-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl"

Comment: @ Vadim Shkaberda : I tried a new version 1.5.1

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Numpy - ImportError: cannot import name shares\_memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38385467/numpy-importerror-cannot-import-name-shares-memory)

Answer (score 1):

I soled the issue by uninstalling python27, reinstall it again and install extension
pip install matplotlib-1.5.0-cp27-none-win_amd64.whl

this will install automaticaly numpy extension