# Error importing numpy package

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to run this simple code

```
import numpy as np

bmi = np.array([12,123,34])
print bmi
```

When I execute it however I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "sample10.py", line 1, in <module>
 import numpy as np
File "C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 142, in <module>
from . import add_newdocs
File "C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
File "C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
from .type_check import *
File "C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
File "C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
from . import function_base
File "C:\Users\Marc\AppData\Local\Enthought\Canopy\User\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\function_base.py", line 6, in <module>
from .numeric import result_type, NaN, shares_memory, MAY_SHARE_BOUNDS,   TooHardError
ImportError: cannot import name shares_memory
```

Any thoughts what might be causing this? When Im running

```
python --version
```

I get 2.7.11

Comment: Perhaps a bad installation? Take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38385467/numpy-importerror-cannot-import-name-shares-memory

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Numpy - ImportError: cannot import name shares\_memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38385467/numpy-importerror-cannot-import-name-shares-memory)