# Python error: "ImportError: cannot import name isnat"

Tags: python, numpy, pip, vpython

Python is throwing the following error:

```
File "C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\numpy\core\arrayprint.py", line 42
    from .umath import absolute, not_equal, isnan, isinf, isfinite, isnat   
ImportError: cannot import name isnat
```

It is weird because I haven't able to find the `isnat` documentation. My numpy version is 1.14.0, which seems to be the only library that cannot be loaded from `.umath`.

Comment: Try https://stackoverflow.com/a/40366276/1283083

Comment: I have done it already, but it didn't work. Thank you

Comment: It's documented [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.isnat.html).

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue, and likewise reinstalling using the command from https://stackoverflow.com/a/40366276/1283083 did not help.

However, I was able to get numpy to import by running the following command from the command prompt as admin:

```
pip install -U --force-reinstall numpy
```

Not sure why exactly that worked, but numpy loads in my IDE now. I got the command from https://github.com/dwhswenson/contact_map/blob/master/docs/installing.rst